# Definition of a simple function in fine structure theory

Tags: set-theory

I have a few questions on the definition of a simple function and I hope someone can help me with them.

First let me give some context. Let $E$ be a set or a proper class. We say a function or relation is $\text{rud}_E,$ if it is rudimentary in $E$. And for any transitive set $U$, $\text{rud}_E(U)$ denotes the closure of $U$ under $\text{rud}_E$ functions. We say $U$ is $\text{rud}_E$ closed iff $\text{rud}_E(U) \subseteq U$. Also the structures we deal with here are of the form $\langle M, \in, E\cap M\rangle$.

This is the definition:

> Call a function $f:V^k \rightarrow V$, where $k \lt \omega$, *simple* iff the following holds true: if $\varphi(v_0, v_1, \dots, v_k)$ is $\Sigma_0$ in the $\mathcal{L}_{\in,E}$, then $\varphi(f(v_1', \dots, v_k'), v_1, \dots, v_k)$ is equivalent over transitive $\text{rud}_E$ closed structures to a $\Sigma_0$ formula in the same language.

So here are my questions:

- Since we say *simple* with no mention of $E$(like *simple*$_E$ for example), does it mean that we quantify over all $E$, in the definition? Or we don't mention it, because we have already fixed $E$?
- The equivalent formula that we get in the definition, is it uniform? Meaning that: Do we expect to have one formula that is equivalent over all structures mentioned above to the original formula? Or do we get one equivalent formula for each structure?(The latter seems extreme to me, as it would require lots of coding of syntax and such.)
- And lastly, it seems to me that the restriction to $\text{rud}_E$ closed structures is redundant. Since if this holds for all transitive structures, then it certainly does for $\text{rud}_E$ closed structures. And if it holds for all $\text{rud}_E$ closed structures, given an arbitrary structure $\langle M, \in, E\cap M\rangle$, we can look at $\langle \text{rud}_E(M), \in, E\cap \text{rud}_E(M)\rangle$ and then by absoluteness we can come back down, because the formula in question is $\Sigma_0$. So is the restriction to $\text{rud}_E$ closed structures necessary?

---

EDIT I:

The definition here can be found in Ralf Schindler's book "Set Theory: Exploring Independence and Truth", the edition for Feb. $28$ $2014$, Page $70$, in the middle of the proof of lemma $5.11$.

---

EDIT II:

I also would really appreciate if someone could put the definition above in terms of symbols and mathematical language, since I think that could resolve both my first two questions and some other minor questions that I have.

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it is from Ralf Schindler's book. I have added a more precise reference in the edit.

Comment: For the second, I *believe* the definition is uniform for $E$, as many theorems and concepts  (like the canonical global well-ordering over $J_\alpha$) on Jensen's article on Fine structure theory appears uniform.

Comment: For the first, I think both interpretations are equally correct, and they are the same. Schindler defined $E$-simple function for *all* $E$ uniformly. By not mentioning any conditions for $E$, we can indirectly quantify $E$, and it could turn into an explicit qualification by using the universal introduction over the metatheory.

Comment: @HanulJeon, thanks! Can you please expand a bit more on your second comment? I don't seem to understand it correctly. What I mean by my first question is that do we either mean that (1) once given a formula we find an equivalnet formula over transitive rud$_E$ closed structures for that E that we have fixed? Or (2) once given a formula we find an equivalnet formula over transitive rud$_E$ closed structures for all E at once?(which again needs coding of syntax for proper class E's, to write this formula in $\mathcal{L}_\in$.)

Comment: The point I want to say is, the fixed $E$ in your (1) is still arbitrary, as we assume nothing on $E$. Hence I think the universal quantifier for $E$ is suppressed in (1).

Comment: Also, I could somewhat deviate the main issue in the initial comment: uniformity. As far as I caught, (1) could mean the definition possibly depends on $E$. However, the definition of simple functions is already uniform for $E$ in context.

Comment: I read (1) as "For each $E$, we have a definition of simple functions...", and (2) as "There is a definition schema, which does not depend on $E$, of simple functions..." The definition of simple function already follows (2).

Comment: (Sorry, the gist of the comment is changed. I am also confusing about meta-language associated issues. Also, I am going to sleep, as here it is almost 4 a.m, so any further comments will be delayed.)

Comment: @HanulJeon, okay. So I think I have come to some conclusion. What I had in mind with (2) was something like this: we have coded everything in ZFC and the definition is in ZFC and not the meta-theory, and we say $f$ is simple iff for all $\phi$ we have some $\psi$ which for all $E$, over any rud$_E$ structure, $\phi(f)$ and $\psi$ are equivalent. But I suppose what you are saying, is that all this is defined in the meta-theory and $E$ is just a "free variable" in the meta-language of our meta-theory, right? If this is the case, then I think I can get behind that.

Comment: @HanulJeon, also I would appreciate it if you could tell me your opinion on my third question, when you are back. Also have you seen this definition somewhere else? Maybe I could get a better idea of it, by looking around.

Comment: Yes. $E$ includes any proper class, so I think there is no way to quantify it (unless we use NBG or MK or something similar) on the theory we are working on. This is the reason why I think the quantification lies in the metatheory.

Comment: The only references I have seen the definition of the simple function are Jensen's original paper, which just contains a simpler definition (it consider the case $E=0$) or Schindler's chapter in *Handbook of Set theory* (I cannot remember the definition, but I guess it is identical with what you are using.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to give some input. So first of all, this definition appears in a proof, so it should be understood in the context of the proof. The $E$ is fixed in the statement of the lemma and thus it is not quantified over in the definition, so what simple means in the proof maybe should be called $E$-simple and being $E$-simple can be different from being $F$-simple for $E\neq F$.

Regarding your second question, in the definition it is not required that the equivalent $\Sigma_0$-formula is uniform in the structures. To finish the proof, one only needs that all $\operatorname{rud}_E$-functions are simple in this sense (as this is quite tedious to do, this statement was packaged as an exercise). The uniformity is not relevant. Anyhow, doing this exercise reveals that for $\operatorname{rud}_E$-functions these formulas can be chosen uniformly. Indeed even more is true: In the same way as one can associate natural numbers to first order formulas by looking at how they are build from the atomic formulas and the connectives, one can do this with rudimentary functions. There is then a recursive map $\eta:\operatorname{Fml}_{\in, E}\times\omega\rightarrow\operatorname{Fml}_{\in, E}$ so that whenever $f$ is $\operatorname{rud}_E$ and $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_0$ $\{\in, E\}$-formula then $\varphi(f(v_0, \dots, v_n), w_0, \dots , w_m)$ is equivalent to $\eta(\varphi, k)(v_0, \dots, v_n, w_0,\dots, w_m)$ over any transitive $\operatorname{rud}_E$-closed structure, where $k$ is the natural number associated to $f$. [Again, E is fixed here]

Lastly, the reason why one quantifies over not just all transitive but moreover $\operatorname{rud}_E$-closed strucures is simply that the question whether $\varphi(f(v_0, \dots, v_n), w_0, \dots , w_m)$ is equivalent to $\psi(v_0, \dots, v_n, w_0, \dots , w_m)$ over a structure $\mathcal M=(M, \in, E)$ only makes sense if $M$ is closed under $f$. It means

$$\text{for all }x_0,\dots, x_n, y_0,\dots y_m\in M\ \mathcal M\models \varphi(f(x_0, \dots, x_n), y_0, \dots , y_m)\Leftrightarrow\psi(x_0, \dots, x_n, y_0, \dots , y_m)$$
after all.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I actually had emailed prof. Schindler about this and he sent me an email a few hours ago and I didn't have the time to post it. I'm sorry. He pretty much said the same thing and raised another good point regarding my last question, even if $f$ were total on $M$, then since it's defining formula need not be $\Sigma_0$, we can't use absoluteness in my argument to come back down. I also have one minor question. Since I suspect that not every simple function is rud$_E$, shouldn't we include a clause in the definition that the structures are closed under $f$ too?

Comment: Yes on should do that. One could also limit the definition only to rudimentary in E functions as this is all we care about.

Comment: Also if it's not inappropriate, I have a question from the lemma itself. In the last paragraph of the lemma, since $f$ is simple, we have that $v_0 \in f(v_1, \dots, v_k)$ is equivalent over $\text{rud}_E(U \cup \{U\})$ to a $\Sigma_0$ formula. Then how do we deduce that $x$ is $\Sigma_0^{(U\cup\{U\}, \in, E)}(\{x_1, \dots,x_n\})$? By the simplicity of $f$, we have that $x$ is $\Sigma_0^{(\text{rud}_E(U\cup\{U\}), \in, E)}(\{x_1, \dots,x_n\})$.

Comment: There you can just use $\Sigma_0$-absoluteness.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Many thanks!